# Mockito doNothing with Mockito.mockStatic

Tags: mockito, junit5

I'm using Mockito, along with [mockito-inline](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#48) for mocking static methods. I'm trying to apply `doNothing` or similar behavior, to a static void method. The following workaround work, but I think that there should have a more convenient way to achieve this with less code.

```
try (MockedStatic<UtilCalss> mock = Mockito.mockStatic(UtilCalss.class)) {

     mock.when(() -> UtilCalss.staticMethod(any()))
            .thenAnswer((Answer<Void>) invocation -> null);

}
```

If it's a non-static method, we could simply do:

```
doNothing().when(mock).nonStaticMethod(any());
```

But I want to do the same for a static method.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You don't need to stub that call.

`doNothing` is a default behaviour of a `void` method called on a mock.

Example:

Class under test:

```java
public class UtilClass {
    public static void staticMethod(String data) {
        System.out.println("staticMethod called: " + data);
    }
}
```

Test code:

```java
public class UtilClassTest {
    @Test
    void testMockStaticForVoidStaticMethods() {
        try (MockedStatic<UtilClass> mockStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(UtilClass.class)) {
            UtilClass.staticMethod("inMockStaticScope");
        }
        UtilClass.staticMethod("outOfMockStaticScope");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
staticMethod called: outOfMockStaticScope
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to get it to work? At least the above example in the question doesn't work.

Comment: And what about for non-void methods?

Comment: @Matt same as for non-void non-static methods. If not stubbed, they return default value for their return type.

Comment: If I leave it as 
objMock.when(() -> Obj.staticFunc(any()))
I get an error during execution "UnfinishedStubbingException".  I don't see why this answer has the highest score.

Comment: @OuuGiii just declare the mock : 
MockedStatic<UtilCalss> mock = Mockito.mockStatic(UtilCalss.class) 
 then call the method under test classUnderTest.methodUsingTheMock()

Comment: Some examples please!

Answer (score 6):

mockito-inline include mockito-core :

```sh
        <!-- Mockito-inline include Mockito-code in same version - Useful for Mock static method -->
        <!-- See https://asolntsev.github.io/en/2020/07/11/mockito-static-methods/ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.28</version>
        </dependency>
```

And if static method you are testing return nothing => don't use mock.when => just execute the method you want to test and verify :

```java
try (MockedStatic<UtilClass> mock = Mockito.mockStatic(UtilClass.class)) {

     mock.when(() -> UtilClass.staticMethod(any()))
            .thenAnswer((Answer<Void>) invocation -> null);

     App.main(null); // example : I'm testing main method from App class

     mock.verify(UtilClass::staticMethod); // I verify static method from UtilClass was called.

}
```

**resources** :

- [Mocking static methods with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito)
- https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2027 - cf rimuln comment on 16 Oct 2020

Comment: I don't get it; you say "don't use mock.when", but then the code that you've posted *does* use mock.when. Is there a copy-paste error or something?

Comment: This actually works, unlike the incorrect answer by Lesiak.